# Getting an element by attribute and using driver to click on a child element in webscraping - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Webscraping results from Indeed.com

-Searching 'Junior Python' in 'Los Angeles, CA' (Done)

-Sometimes popup window opens. Close the window if popup occurs.(Done)

-Top 3 results are sponsored so skip these and go to real results

-Click on result summary section which opens up side panel with full summary

-Scrape the full summary

-When result summary is clicked, url changes. Rather than opening new window, I would like to scrape the side panel full summary

-Each real result is under `('div':{'data-tn-component':'organicJob'})`. I am able to get jobtitle, company, and short summary using BeautifulSoup. However, I would like to get the full summary on the side panel.

Problem

1) When I try to click on the link(using Selenium) (jobtitle or the short summary, which opens up the side panel), the code only ends up clicking on the 1st link which is the 'sponsored'. Unable to locate and click on real result under id='jobOrganic'

2) Once a real result is clicked on(manually), I can see that the full summary side panel is under `<td id='auxCol'>` and within this, under . The full summary is contained within the `<p>` tags. When I try to have a selenium scrape full summary using `findAll('div':{'id':'vjs-desc'})`, all I get is blank result [].

3) The url also changes when the side panel is opened. I tried using Selenium to have driver get the new url and then soup the url to get results but all I'm getting is the 1st sponsored result which is not what I want. I'm not sure why BeautifulSoup keeps getting the result for sponsored, even when I'm running the code under `'id='jobOrganic'` real results.

Here is my code. I've been working on this for almost past two days, went through stackoverflow, documentation, and google but unable to find the answer. I'm hoping someone can point out what I'm doing wrong and why I'm unable to get the full summary.

Thanks and sorry for this being so long.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs    

url = 'https://www.indeed.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

whatinput = driver.find_element_by_id('text-input-what')
whatinput.send_keys('Junior Python')

whereinput = driver.find_element_by_id('text-input-where')
whereinput.click()
whereinput.clear()
whereinput.send_keys('Los Angeles, CA')

findbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="whatWhere"]/form/div[3]/button')
findbutton.click()

try:
    popup = driver.find_element_by_id('prime-popover-close-button')
    popup.click()
except:
    pass
```

This is where I'm stuck. The result summary is under {'data-tn-component':'organicJob'}, span class='summary'. Once I click on this, side panel opens up.

```
soup = bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
contents = soup.findAll('div',{"data-tn-component":"organicJob"})
for each in contents:
    summary = driver.find_element_by_class_name('summary')
    summary.click()
```

This opens side panel but it clicks the first sponsored link in the whole page (sponsored link), not the real result. This basically goes out of the 'organicJob' resultset for some reason.

```
url = driver.current_url
driver.get(url)
```

I tried to set the new url after clicking on the link(sponsored) to test out whether I can even get the side panel full summary(albeit sponsored, as test purpose).

```
soup=bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
fullsum = soup.findAll('div',{"id":"vjs-desc"})
print(fullsum)
```

This actually prints out the full summary of side panel, but it keeps printing the same 1st result over and over through the whole loop, instead of moving to the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are fetching `div`s using beautiful soup but, clicking using selenium which is not aware of your collected divs.
As you are using `find_element_by_class_name()` method of the `driver` object. It searches the whole page instead of your intended div object `each`(in the for loop). Thus, it ends up fetching the same first result from the whole page in each iterations.
One, quick work around is possible using only selenium(this will be slower though)

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
for element in elements:
    if "organicJob" in element.get_attribute("data-tn-component"):
        summary = element.find_element_by_class_name('summary')
        summary.click()
```

The above code will search for all the divs and, iterate over them to find divs with `data-tn-component` attribute containing `organicJob`. Once, it find one it will search for element with class name `summary` and click on that element.

Comment: Nice catch `fetching divs using beautiful soup but, clicking using selenium` +1 !!!